# Could not find schema information for the element

Tags: asp.net, xml, xsd

I am working on a concept [`EFile`](http://www.irs.gov/efile/)

I wrote the sample structure as per specified in the `PDF's` but i am unable to validate the `XML` data i am getting the following errors when i execute that `XML` file.

```
Could not find schema information for the element 'ReturnData'.Validation event
Could not find schema information for the attribute 'documentCount'.Validation event
Could not find schema information for the attribute 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Instance:NamespaceSchemaLocation'.Validation event
Could not find schema information for the element 'ContentLocation'.Document is invalid
```

Can any one help me on this in-order to resolve my issues.

The sample `XML` is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReturnData documentCount="" 
            xsi:NamespaceSchemaLocation="D:\foldername\XML\XMLValidate\ReturnData941.xsd"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Instance">
  <ContentLocation />
</ReturnData>
```

This is my code

```
public void MyValidationEventHandler(object sender,
                                        ValidationEventArgs args)
{
    isValid = false;
    Response.Write("Validation event<br/>" + args.Message);
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strPath1 = Server.MapPath("test.xml");
    XmlTextReader r = new XmlTextReader(strPath1);
    XmlValidatingReader v = new XmlValidatingReader(r);
    v.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    v.ValidationEventHandler +=
       new ValidationEventHandler(MyValidationEventHandler);
    while (v.Read())
    {
        // Can add code here to process the content.
    }
    v.Close();

    // Check whether the document is valid or invalid.
    if (isValid)
    {
        Response.Write("Document is valid");
        //Response.Redirect("Product.xml");
    }
    else
        Response.Write("Document is invalid");
}
```

Comment: Can any one tell where i went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the code that went wrong it is the import of `XSD` that you made wrong in `XML` just change your `XML` as follows

```
<ReturnData documentCount=""
        xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.irs.gov/efile ReturnData941.xsd"
        >
```

This will works fine...

Comment: Thanks a lot `Dorababu` you just saved my life.. This works perfect for me

Comment: To clarify the xml in the question failed to specify the namespace for the root element ReturnData. It neither defined a default namespace, i.e. xmlns="..." as corrected in this answer, neither did it specify a namespace prefix to the element name, i.e. rd:ReturnData xmlns:rd="..."

Answer (score 0):

Change the `xsi:NamespaceSchemaLocation` to be `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`. Also try making it a URL, like this: `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///D:/foldername/XML/XMLValidate/ReturnData941.xsd`

Comment: See revised answer for something else to try.

Comment: Can you copy your ReturnData941.xsd file to your current directory and try the location without qualification, like "ReturnData941.xsd". The problem is likely that it's not finding this file.

Comment: And finally, my last idea, try "SchemaLocation" instead of noNamespaceSchemaLocation

Comment: That would be "xsi:schemaLocation". Remember XML is case-sensitive.